# iOS 7 iAd cocos2d deprecated

Tags: objective-c, ios7, cocos2d-iphone, deprecated, iad

Im trying to get iAd implemented to a iOS 7 game I made with cocos2d, I added iad framework in xcode and have the setup below

in @implementation I have set

```
   ADBannerView *_bannerView;
```

then

```
-(id)init
{
    if( (self= [super init]) )
    {
        // On iOS 6 ADBannerView introduces a new initializer, use it when available.
        if ([ADBannerView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(initWithAdType:)]) {
            ADBannerView *_adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];

        } else {
            _adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
        }
        _adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
        _adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view]addSubview:_adView];
        [_adView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view]addSubview:_adView];
        _adView.delegate = self;
    }
    [self layoutAnimated:YES];
    return self;
}


- (void)layoutAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // As of iOS 6.0, the banner will automatically resize itself based on its width.
    // To support iOS 5.0 however, we continue to set the currentContentSizeIdentifier appropriately.
    CGRect contentFrame = [CCDirector sharedDirector].view.bounds;
    if (contentFrame.size.width < contentFrame.size.height) {
        //_bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
        [adView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    } else {
        _bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
    }

    CGRect bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;
    if (_bannerView.bannerLoaded) {
        contentFrame.size.height -= _bannerView.frame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    } else {
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? 0.25 : 0.0 animations:^{
        _bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
    }];
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [self layoutAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [self layoutAnimated:YES];
}
```

I get an error about '_adview' and as well as 'currentContentSizeIdentifier' deprecated, can anyone help me get this working correctly?  Ive checked online all day and couldnt get any of the code working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this New Code:

```
- (void)createAdBannerView
{
    _adBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _adBannerView.delegate = self;
   [_adBannerView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

    CGRect frame = _adBannerView.frame;
    frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height;
    frame.origin.x = 0.0f;

    _adBannerView.frame = frame;

    AppDelegate * app = (((AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate));
    [app.navController.view addSubview:_adBannerView];
}
```

[Here new iAd Code for Cocos2d 3.0.](https://app.box.com/s/fr5ya0hyf322gfd7gntx)

[image]

Comment: I get 'ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait' is deprecated. as well for 'currentContentSizeIdentifier', do you know the ios 7 replacement code for those?

Comment: where I used ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait ? remove currentContentSizeIdentifier, and use setAutoresizingMask.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm :) Thank you for taking time to help me out with this, I've been struggling with this the past few days lol

Comment: I get a error when I try to run the downloaded project in the simulator, 'Thread1: signal SIGABRT' saying cannot be nil

Comment: reset simulator and restart Xcode then run…if still crashed then restart your system then try…I guess in Xcode issue…here working fine.

Comment: Ok started working perfectly thanks Guru! :) using this method can I use Interstitial ads as well?

Comment: Actually I couldn't get this to work without changing 1 line:

    _adBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

to:

    _adBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,navController.view.frame.size.width,0.0)];

Comment: @PKCLsoft I guess in landscape mode right? In portrait it works with CGRectZero.

Comment: Correct, sorry I should have said that.  In landscape it places a 320px banner at the top center if I don't specify the width of the screen.